# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end

Tags: php

Выдаёт такую ошибку 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test.php on line 17

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться

```html
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

## Жесткая ссылка на несуществующий элемент массива.
$l = array(
'вилка' => '271 руб. 82 коп.',
'сковорода' => '818 руб. 28 коп.'
);
$b =& $l['ложка']; // $b — то же, что и элемент с индексом 'ложка'
echo "Элемент с индексом 'ложка': ".$l['ложка']."<br>";
echo "Тип несуществующего элемента 'ложка': ".gettype($l['ложка']);
foreach ( $l as $key => $value){
 echo "Name: $key, Age: $value <br />";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Закрывающая фигурная скобка забыта.`foreach` не закрыт

правильно так:

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

## Жесткая ссылка на несуществующий элемент массива.
$l = array(
'вилка' => '271 руб. 82 коп.',
'сковорода' => '818 руб. 28 коп.'
);
$b =& $l['ложка']; // $b — то же, что и элемент с индексом 'ложка'
echo "Элемент с индексом 'ложка': ".$l['ложка']."<br>";
echo "Тип несуществующего элемента 'ложка': ".gettype($l['ложка']);
foreach ( $l as $key => $value){
    echo "Name: $key, Age: $value <br />";
};
?>
```

Comment: спасибо большое! буду внимательнее смотреть в дальнейшем

Comment: пиши в IDE.. там такие ошибка сразу помечает..да и скобки все само ставит...ну или блокнот с плагинами различными

Comment: IDE для слабаков. Блокнот наше всё

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  Notepad++ ❤❤❤❤❤

Comment: @ReaGedLLC notepad++ тоже для слабаков, там тоже есть небольшой, но автокомплит и даже zenCoding. Даешь обычный майкрософт нотпад!)

Comment: Остановился на  PHPStorm